# Git/Heroku - get latest files

Tags: git, heroku

I've only just started using Heroku and I'm new to Git.

I've got a site where people can upload an image - and the image is saved in a folder `uploads`. When the site is live and I upload an image `uploads` folder now has an additional file that does not exist on my local. How can I use `git` to get latest version of what's on my server? I.e. - I want to get the changes that happened on the server - so that `uploads` on my local also has the image in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you can use Git to get the file is if the file is committed to the remote repo on your server. If or when it is, you can then just `git fetch` or `git pull` it.

If it isn't committed, you'll have to use some other means to retrieve the file (like FTP), and then you can commit it to your local repo.

Comment: Okay so just to make sure I understand correctly - if a file was added to the server by means other than git (e.g. it was generated automatically) there's no way to get it on your local through git?

Comment: There is no way to retrieve the file using Git unless the file is committed into a remote Git repo.